# "mismatched types: expected `i16`, found `Result`" in a number guessing game

Tags: rust

I am making a random number guessing program with Rust but when I check for an actual number I get an error that says "expected `i16`, found enum `std::result::Result`".

```
use rand::Rng; // 0.8.0
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};
use std::process;
use std::result::Result;

fn read(input: &mut String) {
    stdout().flush().expect("failed to flush");
    stdin().read_line(input).expect("failed to read");
}

fn main() {
    loop {
        let mut number = String::new();
        let rand_ = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..10);
        let mut killcheck = String::new();

        println!("Input a number between 0 and 10 \n");
        match rand_ {
            1..=5 => println!("it is 1 through 5"),
            5..=10 => println!("it is 5 through 10"),
            _ => continue,
        }
        read(&mut number);



        let number: i16 = number.trim().parse::<i16>().unwrap();
        match number {
            Ok(ok) => continue,
            Err(e) => println!("No number could be found"),
            _ => continue
        }

        read(&mut killcheck);



        if killcheck.trim() == "end" {
            println!("error is null");
            process::exit(0x0100);
        }

        if number == rand_ {
            println!("Currect!\n")
        }
        if number != rand_ {
            println!("Incorrect!\n")
        }

        read(&mut killcheck);
        if killcheck.trim() == "end" {
            println!("error is null");
            process::exit(0x0100);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand the problem, I would think it would just be checking if it can happen then continue.

Comment: Please always post the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: You're `unwrap()`ing, what did you expect?

Comment: expected `i16`, found enum `Result`   is the error i get

Comment: Run `cargo check` in the terminal, don't post the error you get from your IDE.

Comment: I guess the problem lies on the `parse::<i16>()` method failed to recognized the result of `number.trim()` as a suitable string. You should post the entire error from `cargo check` so someone could help you

Comment: @DennyHiu: that would be a runtime error, whereas OP describes a compile-time type mismatch.

Answer (score -1):

```rust
let number: i16 = number.trim().parse::<i16>().unwrap();  //*number is i16 type with the use of unwrap() instead of Result*

match number {

     Ok(ok) => continue,  //*It should be some i16 numbers here instead of Result(Ok/Err)*

     Err(e) => println!("No number could be found"),

     _ => continue

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).